# How to stop a while true loop using conditionals?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to have my `while True` loop end when the user input for the hex number is found to be "stop" or "Stop". However, each time I try to test it, the condition never goes through and instead it enters the first conditional and treats it like a regular number so that the loop never ends.

I tried moving the "stop" conditional above the first conditional and all it did was give the `print` statement but keeps the loop running and trying to return false didn't stop the loop either.

Are my conditionals wrong or is it my logic?

```
def hex_to_words():
    while True:
        hex_num = input("Enter a Hex Number Watney: ")
        print(hex_num)
        if hex_num != "Stop" or hex_num != "stop":
            if len(hex_num) <= 2:
                letter = chr((int(hex_num,16)))
                print(letter)
                if any(x not in allowed_characters for x in letter):
                    print("error: invalid number")
                    hex_to_words()
                else:
                    letArray.append(letter)
                    print(letArray)
                    hex_to_words()
            elif len(hex_num) > 2:
                print("Keep the number to two digits Watney!")
        else:
            print("Program shutting down...")
            #return False
            break

hex_to_words()
```

Comment: `if hex_num != "Stop" or hex_num != "stop":` this is always true, so the else branch is never entered. Replace `or` with `and`.

Comment: You can also normalize the input: `if hex_num.lower() != 'stop':`

Comment: Why are you doing `while True:` and then using a `break`?  Just do `while hex_num not in ("Stop", "stop"):`

Comment: @9769953 i replaced the or for and but I still continue to have the loop never end and it always going to the first conditional instead of ending the loop. I also took defladamouse's advice but then it just continues appending the last letter that was put in every time I write stop

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily want to do it with recursion, you need to break after your recursive call to hex_to_words(), otherwise you will break out of the innermost function call but the while loop in the previous calls will not be broken. So write

```
def hex_to_words():
    while True:
        hex_num = input("Enter a Hex Number Watney: ")
        print(hex_num)
        if hex_num != "Stop" and hex_num != "stop":
            if len(hex_num) <= 2:
                letter = chr((int(hex_num,16)))
                print(letter)
                if any(x not in allowed_characters for x in letter):
                    print("error: invalid number")
                    hex_to_words()
                    break
                else:
                    letArray.append(letter)
                    print(letArray)
                    hex_to_words()
                    break
            elif len(hex_num) > 2:
                print("Keep the number to two digits Watney!")
        else:
            print("Program shutting down...")
            #return False
            break

hex_to_words()
```

Also, change `or` to `and` as suggested in the comments. However, there is no need for this to be a recursive function and I would in fact argue that recursion makes it less clear and is probably also slower and more prone to stack overflow. A better version is to simply remove the recursive call and the program will work as is:

```
def hex_to_words():
    while True:
        hex_num = input("Enter a Hex Number Watney: ")
        print(hex_num)
        if hex_num != "Stop" and hex_num != "stop":
            if len(hex_num) <= 2:
                letter = chr((int(hex_num,16)))
                print(letter)
                if any(x not in allowed_characters for x in letter):
                    print("error: invalid number")
                else:
                    letArray.append(letter)
                    print(letArray)
            elif len(hex_num) > 2:
                print("Keep the number to two digits Watney!")
        else:
            print("Program shutting down...")
            #return False
            break

hex_to_words()
```